# Printing from servlet, why does this not work

Tags: java, html, servlets, printing

I want to print from a servlet. I believe I have the correct syntax. But I get the message "delete these tokens" in Eclipse.

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    out.println("<html><head><title>Woohoo</title></head><body>\n" + 

            "<form id="report_form" name="report_form" method="post" action="AgReportServlet">\n"+
            "<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">\n"+
                "<tr>\n"+
                "   <td><label>Start Date<br />\n"+
                "   <select name="start_date" id="start_date">\n"+
                "       <option value="2000">2000</option>\n" +
                "       <option value="2001">2001</option>\n" +
                "       <option value="2002">2002</option>\n" +
                "       <option value="2003">2003</option>\n" +
                "       <option value="2004">2004</option>\n" +
                "   </select> </label></td>\n"+
                "   <td>End Date<br />\n"+
                "   <select name="end_date" id="end_date">\n"+
                "       <option value="2000">2000</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="2001">2001</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="2002">2002</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="2003">2003</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="2004">2004</option>\n"+
                "   </select></td>\n"+
                "   <td><label>Agricultural Zone<br />\n"+
                "   <select name="ag_zone" id="ag_zone">\n"+
                "       <option value="1">Zone 1</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="2">Zone 2</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="3">Zone 3</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="4">Zone 4</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="5">Zone 5</option>\n"+
                "   </select> </label></td>\n"+
                "   <td><label>Locality<br />\n"+
                "   <select name="locality" id="locality">\n"+
                "       <option value="here">There</option>\n"+
                "       <option value="there">There</option>\n"+
                "   </select> </label></td>\n"+
                "   <td><label><br />\n"+
                "   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> </label></td>\n"+
                "</tr>\n"+
        "   </table>\n"+
        "   </form>\n"+
        "</body>\n"+
        "</html>"
            );
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

The stack trace is as follows:
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens 
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens 
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2000", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2001", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2002", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2003", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2004", [ expected 
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2000", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2001", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2002", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String 
    Syntax error on token "2003", [ expected 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

etc. etc.

Comment: Its good to know the basics. No offense, I am your friend. Its not enough to do it, you must do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting double quotes inside your string like:

```
"<form id="report_form"...
```

You need to escape them:

```
"<form id=\"report_form\"...
```

or use single quotes in the HTML:

```
"<form id='report_form'...
```

Comment: @Ankur: Beside all this, you are creating an evil.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this isn't what you want to do. Try [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) instead.